# Replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, replace

Criei um script pra inserir uma div no carrinho da minha loja, mas a está dando erro na função replace. Alguém saberia o por que ?

```
var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
$JQuery(function(){ 
var ValorFreteGratis = 299;
var PrecoTotal = '{{order_total}}';
var QuantoFalta = ValorFreteGratis - PrecoTotal;
var NumeroComVirgula = QuantoFalta.replace(".", ",");
if(PrecoTotal < ValorFreteGratis){
$JQuery('<div class="msg-free_shipping"> <p><span class="warning">EI!!:</span> Comprando mais R$' + NumeroComVirgula.toFixed(2) + ' <span class="restante">você aproveita o <strong>FRETE GRÁTIS</strong> nas compras acima de R$<span class="valor-gratis">' + ValorFreteGratis + '</span></p> </div>').insertAfter('form#cart_update_post');}});
```

Fica dando o erro: "Uncaught TypeError: QuantoFalta.replace is not a function"

Comment: Provavelmente `QuantoFalta` não é uma string, talvez `undefined` ou `NaN`. Vefifique assim: `console.log(typeof QuantoFalta)` antes da linha que aplica o `replace`.

Comment: QuantoFalta é `number` pela conta, é necessário converter para `string`

Comment: Se QuantoFalta não for `string` tu pode fazer isso: `String(QuantoFalta).replace...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A função `replace` é uma função do tipo `String`. A variável `QuantoFalta` é produto de uma operação matemática, logo não é uma `String`. Utilize `toString` para transformá-la:

```
 ...
 ... QuantoFalta.toString().replace(...
 ...
```

---

> [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
>
> O método `replace()` retorna uma nova string com algum ou todas as combinações do padrão substituído por um substituto.

Answer (score 4):

Seu problema é com tipagem (é possível perceber pelo `TypeError`), como você está fazendo uma subtração, todo o resultado se torna do tipo `number`, logo, a função `replace` não existe.

```js
var x = 10 - 5; // deve dar 5
console.log(x) // 5
console.log(typeof x) // number
x.replace(5, 10) // Uncaught TypeError
```

O que pode ser feito é alterar o tipo da variável, utilizando `String(valor)`:

```js
    var x = 10 - 5; // deve dar 5
    console.log(x) // 5
    
    x = String(x).replace('5', 'agora foi') // note o uso do String(x)
    console.log(x) // "agora foi"
    
    // O string pode ser feito na conta também
    // Ex:
    var y = String(10 - 5)
    console.log(y)
```

Geralmente esses erros causam confusão por o Javascript não ser uma linguagem bem tipada, não é necessário explicitar isso durante o uso.
E outra coisa que também pode gerar problemas é, você pode substrair/multiplicar/dividir `strings` e elas se tornarão `number`, mas não pode somá-las, já que é o mesmo caractere utilizado para concatenar, isso
outra coisa que pode criar esse tipo de confusão.

```js
console.log(typeof ('10' - '5')) // number (5)
console.log(typeof (10 + 5)) // number (15)
console.log(typeof ('10' + 5)) // string ('105') 
console.log(typeof (10 + '5')) // string ('105')
console.log(typeof ('10' + '5')) // string ('105')
```

Answer (score 1):

o replace só pode ser dado com String. Altere para:

`var numeroComVirgula = String(QuantoFalta).replace('.',',')`